# angularjs promises waiting for 3 services to complete before showing message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a checkbox with 3 selections on the UI, each checkbox selection will represent an independent service to fulfill. However, since these services are variably invoked, I need to come up with a way to wait for all selected options to complete until showing messaging.

so basically, initial implementation was this:

```
if (doA) {
   mysvc.doA();
}

if (doB) {
   mysvc.doB();
}

if (doC) {
   mysvc.doC();
}

window.alert('success');
```

Then I realized I need to wait for all of them to complete, so I came up with this:

```
if (doA) {
   mysvc.doA();
}

if (doB) {
   mysvc.doB();
}

if (doC) {
   mysvc.doC();
}

setTimeout(function () {
    window.alert('success');
}, 8000);
```

Because the operations typically take at maximum of 8 seconds to complete if all selected. But this is obviously not ideal. Also, I would ultimately like to give feedback for each individual operation at the end. Any helps or resources will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $q.all:

```
var promises = [];
if (doA) {
   promises.push(mysvc.doA);

}

if (doB) {
   promises.push(mysvc.doB);
}

if (doC) {
   promises.push(mysvc.doC);
}

$q.all(promises).then(function(d){
    window.alert('success');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you attach a variable to each call then only show success when they're all true?

```
var doaCheck = false;
var dobCheck = false;
var docCheck = false;

if (doA) {
   mysvc.doA();
   doaCheck = true;
}

if (doB) {
   mysvc.doB();
   dobCheck = true;
}

if (doC) {
   mysvc.doC();
   docCheck = true;
}

if (doaCheck && dobCheck && docCheck ) {
   window.alert('success');
   // code to reset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most proper way to do this is with promises using angular's [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Each function should return a promise, then you can take all 3 promises and use $q.all to combine them together and have a callback function that runs only once all 3 are done. Here's an [example with $http promises](https://www.jonathanfielding.com/combining-promises-angular/), but you can do it for anything by creating your own promises using $q.defer() as done here: [example using $q.defer()](http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasBurleson/QqKuk/)

```
    q1 = $scope.q1 = $q.defer(),
    q2 = $scope.q2 = $q.defer(),
    p1 = $scope.q1.promise, 
    p2 = $scope.q2.promise;


    $scope.fromThen = $q.all([
                            p1.then(thenFn), 
                            p2.then(thenFn)
                        ])
                        .then(function(values) {        
                            console.log(values);
                            return values;
                        });
```